# NUnit Parallel - Sequential - Parallel layers

Tags: c#, .net, nunit

We are using NUnit for regression testing on our QA cloud environment, and due to scalability of testing on a common environment that involves the management of heavy objects / processes would like to achieve the following 3 layered test structure:

1. Top-level layer, these can run in parallel, are isolated from one-another
2. Inside each top-level layer, there should be a sequence of ordered "steps" these need to be in an ordered sequence and can't run parallel to other steps in the same top-level layer, BUT can run concurrently with steps of other top-level layers.
3. Bottom-level: actual test cases inside each of the sequential steps. These can again run parallel with eachother from the same sequential-step, or from any of the other top-level layer's test cases.

I can get a "2 layered" solution working, where for example I lose the parallelization of the top-level layer, but that is not good enough as one top-level layer takes quite some time due to IO.

What I have tried:

1. [ParallelScope.Self] and [TestFixture] on the top-level, [ParallelScope.Children] and [Order...] on the sequential-steps. The top-level fixtures do not run parallel, despite the [ParallelScope.Self], even if they are in the same namespace.
2. adding [aseembly: ParallelScope.Children] causes everything to run in parallel
3. adding [ParallelScope.Children | ParallelScope.None] to the sequential steps causes them to be sequential among ALL top-level fixtures, while I only want them to be sequential inside a single one.
4. adding [assembly: ParallelScope.Fixtures] also causes everything to run in parallel

Example instance in time during the test run:

```
1. TopLevelScenarioOne - "running (until all its steps are done)"
1.1. FirstStep - "running (until all its cases are done)"
1.1.1 TestCaseA - "running"
1.1.2 TestCaseB - "running"
1.2 SecondStep - "waiting to start (until the previous step is done)"
1.2.1 TestCaseA - "waiting to start"
1.2.2 TestCaseB - "waiting to start"
2. TopLevelScenarioTwo - "running"
2.1 FirstStep - "done"
2.1.1 TestCaseA - "done"
2.1.2 TestCaseB - "done"
2.2 SecondStep - "running"
2.2.1 TestCaseA - "done"
2.2.2 TestCaseB - "running"
```

And so on. Each top level scenario involves creating a heavy "object", each step involves progressing the heavy object's lifecycle, and each test case involves asserting various services against the expected state for the given heavy object, in its given lifecycle state.

I am aware that the "bottom level" testcases could be collapsed to one test case, with multiple assertions, but these testcases assert against independent systems, and the point of using a testing framework for this is to utilize the testcases and make it clearly visible which parts of the system failed.

Comment: In general, you can't use [Parallelizable] to achieve what you want since NUnit provides no mechanism to control which tests can run in parallel with one another. I could suggest some possible approaches with more information. Can you explain better in your question how you are representing each of the three layers? You've said that the "top" layer is a test fixture but the rest is a  bit vague.

Comment: It is vague because this is a new project, so I can juggle with the actual implementation. Added a more concrete example for the desired result.